# How do i handle if a NodeSelect is nill in C#

Tags: c#, null, try-catch

Ok so I am new to C# but a very experienced developer in other langauges but i dont know how to handle if the NodeSelect is nill

```
 DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(root_path);
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object. 
 xmlDoc.Load(root_path +  @"\file.xml"); //* load the XML document from the specified file. 
        //* Get elements.
  XmlNodeList elements = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//elements");
  foreach (XmlNode node in elements){
    string link = node.SelectSingleNode("link").InnerText.Trim();
```

In the above example link may or maynot be in the element block in the xml and i need it to not give me this error

```
NULLReferenceExemption 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I figured a try catch would work but i know there has got to be a better way in C#

UPDATE

```
            var linkNode = node.SelectSingleNode("link");
            if (linkNode != null)
            {
                string link = linkNode.InnerText.Trim();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("link: " + link);
```

error is Error

```
 The name 'link' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Depends what you want to do in the event that the value is null?

Comment: I would like to set it to an empty string

Comment: On a related note, parsing XML this way is difficult and error prone. Instead you should use a serialization class with a serialization engine like DataContract or protocol buffers. There are many examples and Q/A regarding this.

Comment: @Indeera - do you have a snippet or a link to how to implement serialization...I am new to C#

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: The error in your update is because the variable link is out of scope.  It is only visible inside the if block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, if the `link` node may or may not be there, you have to test for its existence before accessing its methods and properties.

something in the sort of

```
var ln = node.SelectSingleNode("link");
if (ln != null && ln.InnerText!=null)
{
   string link = ln.InnerText.Trim();
   ...
}
```

Comment: And what if InnerText is null?

Comment: @Willem That's why there's a test for it before accessing it

Comment: @Indeera: That's why I should read more carefully, before getting carried away. My apologies :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var linkNode = node.SelectSingleNode("link");
string link = String.Empty;
if (linkNode != null && linkNode.InnerText != null)
   link = linkNode.InnerText.Trim();
```

Comment: And what if InnerText is null?

Comment: @Orsol - ok i will paste in my question ...one sec

Answer (score 0):

You can do, for example,

```
  foreach (XmlNode node in elements)
  {
    var linkNode = node.SelectSingleNode("link");
    if (linkNode != null) 
    {
        string link = linkNode.InnerText.Trim();
    }
  }
```